# Insert picture from file in pcolor cells

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `a` and I want to add pictures from my computer to certain cells whenever I display `pcolor`. I want to add pictures where the ones are. How would I go about that if the picture is in the same directory as the matlab file?

code:

```
 a=[
 1 0 0;
 1 1 0;
 0 0 0];

b=[NaN NaN NaN];

a = [a;b];
b = [b NaN];
b = b.';
a = [a b];

Cmap = [1 1 1];
colormap(Cmap);
pcolor(a)
```

I also have been noticing with `pcolor` that it shifts the matrix by 180 degrees, why is it that so?
This is the pcolor plot that I get:
[image]

I need something like this:
[image]

Here you see the image within pcolor cells, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: [**`subplot`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) , no?

Comment: What is `subplot`? Thanks for the link, I will try now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question this was what I did. I hope this can also help others.

```
    a=[
 1 0 0 0;
 1 1 0 0;
 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0];

aa = a;
ac = aa;

b=[NaN NaN NaN NaN];

a = [a;b];
b = [b NaN];
b = b.';
a = [a b];
I = imread('redirt.jpg');
J = imresize(I, 3, 'nearest');

[x , y] = size(aa);
delete(findall(gcf,'Tag','8puzzle')) 
pos=get(gca,'position'); % getting the position

% calculating position
width=pos(3)/(y); 
height =pos(4)/(x);


Cmap = [1 1 1];
colormap(Cmap);
pcolor(a)
axis off
% loop over the positions/cells you want to place image
for i=1:x
    for j=1:y
        if(aa(i,j) == 1)
            % image position
            axes('pos',[pos(1)+width*(i-1),pos(1)+height*(j-1),width,height], 'Tag','8puzzle');
            % Show image
            imshow(J)                           
        end
        if (i == 4 && j == 4)
            axes('pos',[pos(1)+width*(i-1),pos(1)+height*(j-1),width,height], 'Tag','8puzzle');
            % Show image
            imshow('vacum.jpg')
        end
    end
end
set(gca, 'Ydir', 'reverse');
```

The image overlaps the cells just a little however, it is does not interfere with the display.

[image]